# Trying to trigger breakpoints in Pycharm when running a services through Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, pycharm

I'm trying to set up my Pycharm IDE so that I can put breakpoints in my code that are triggered when running that code in a Docker service as part of a Docker application (defined through `docker-compose.yml`).

Any idea how to do this? I can offer more details if necessary.

**edit**: I was able to make some progress using the following [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html). However, I'm still having difficulty pinging my Flask app which should exist at `localhost:5000`.

I've offered details here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3195451?page=1

Comment: There's a [remote interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) feature in PyCharm Pro. Or do you have a community edition?